# If Static members are not inheriting then why we can access it using sub class reference

Tags: java

If `static` members are not inheriting then why we can access it using sub class reference. Like in the given example we should not be able to access static method from class A by using Class A reference.

```
  package me.addicted.to.java;

    public class B extends A
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            A.method();
            B.method();
            A a1 = new B();
            B test = new B();
            A arr[] = {a1,test};
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
                arr[i].method();
            }
        }

    }
    class A
    {
        static int i = 10;
        static void method(){
            System.out.println("From Hello A");
    }
    }


Output : 

From Hello A

From Hello A

From Hello A

From Hello A
```

Comment: Because they belong to class `A`

Comment: You might look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722682/static-method-behaving-like-other-method-those-can-override/29722779#29722779). It explains why this works. Your compiler/IDE should give you a warning about accessing a static member in a non-static fashion.

Comment: @yshavit Certainly it's a duplicate. The OP here is mistaken in thinking static members aren't inherited, and so evidently are you. You are both confusing inheritance with overriding. NB the duplicated question doesn't ask what you state.

Answer (score 1):

well, `static` members *are* inherited, per JLS's jargon -  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

There's an exception - static methods in interfaces are not inherited.